# Graphviz and ascii output

Tags: ascii, graphviz

Is it possible to draw ASCII diagram using Graphviz?

Something like that:

```
digraph
{
  this -> is
  this -> a
  a -> test
}
```

Gives undesired result.

Instead, I would like to get similar ASCII representation:

```
   this
  /    \
is      a
        |
       test
```

How to draw ascii diagrams from dot-files format?

Comment: [dot to ascii](https://github.com/ggerganov/dot-to-ascii) in Python seems promising.

Comment: [ADia](https://github.com/pylover/adia) may helps.

Answer (score 55):

If you are not perl averse, graph-easy (and the associated `Graph::Easy` package) can do exactly that:

http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Graph-Easy/

http://search.cpan.org/~tels/Graph-Easy/bin/graph-easy

On Mac you can install this with Homebrew and cpan:

```
brew install cpanminus
cpan Graph::Easy
```

It's easy to invoke after installation:

```
cat dotfile.dot   | /opt/local/libexec/perl5.12/sitebin/graph-easy
```

Comment: you could always export a jpeg from graphviz then convert with command line tools like: jp2a --background=light --width=150

Comment: @thamster that'll probably make the text illegible?

Comment: @user3501996 why did you change the links?

Comment: No clue why they did it - rolling back.

Comment: Looks like some folks are talking it upon themselves to prevent version specific links (http://szabgab.com/fixing-cpan-links-from-stack-overflow.html). Since the links I posted aren't version specific and it is CPAN itself - lets leave it at that. *I see MetaCPAN failing well before my version-agnostic CPAN links do.*

Comment: I think the community would be better served adding additional alternative links rather than replacing the existing ones.

Comment: I found it very very useful, thanks @spenthil and thanks to the author of Graph::Easy

Comment: 1. Install `sudo apt-get install cpanminus`. 2. Then this module `sudo cpanm Graph::Easy`. 3. Then you can use it as `cat your.dot | graph-easy --from=dot --as_ascii`

Comment: For anyone trying the example in the question, remove the newline before the `{` — see this bug in graph-easy from 2010: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=63061

Comment: Unfortunately the graph-easy does not support subgraphs.

Answer (score 18):

By now, in ubuntu, you can install and use graph-easy directly:

```
> sudo apt install libgraph-easy-perl
[...]

> graph-easy dotfile.dot 
+----+     +------+
| is | <-- | this |
+----+     +------+
             |
             |
             v
           +------+
           |  a   |
           +------+
             |
             |
             v
           +------+
           | test |
           +------+
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `apt` package but I can endorse graph-easy. It's very useful for README.md files. I hope it never becomes unmaintained.

Comment: I also didn't realize it can generate directly from dot files

Comment: works in debian as well

Answer (score 16):

Here is equivalent commands for linux:

First install cpanminus

```
sudo apt install cpanminus
```

After you can install GraphEasy

```
sudo cpanm Graph::Easy
```

Here is a sample usage

```
cat input.dot | graph-easy --from=dot --as_ascii
```

Comment: For `sudo cpanm Graph::Easy` I get the error `! Installing Graph::Easy failed. See /home/simon/.cpanm/work/1568099378.7482/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.`

Comment: From the logs, my cpanm can't write to  `/usr/local/man`. Seems like a symlink to a nonexisting directory problem: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=583612#10 . Fixed by creating the directory `sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/man/` .

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `Modification of non-creatable array value attempted, subscript -1 at /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1/Graph/Easy/Parser/Graphviz.pm line 928, <STDIN> chunk 1.`  with this. Any idea on how to fix it? The offending line is `return if exists $self->{scope_stack}->[-1]->{_is_group};`.

Comment: This should be marked the right answer, `graph-easy --from=dot --as_ascii` is the short answer to the question

Comment: As of Ubuntu 20.04 (possibly earlier and likely on Debian as well), it's possible to install graph-easy directly with `sudo apt install libgraph-easy-perl`

Answer (score 14):

Another option to use `Graph::Easy`'s ASCII functionality is directly from your browser through this small service that I hosted:

https://dot-to-ascii.ggerganov.com

Answer (score 11):

Using graph-easy via docker. You can install whalebrew and use it to run graph-easy without installing too much dependancies on your local machine other than whalebrew and docker.

on MacOS with homebrew install docker

```
$ brew install docker
$ docker -v      # check if docker is running
```

Install whalebrew - https://github.com/whalebrew/whalebrew (check installation alternatives)

```
$ brew install whalebrew
```

Install graph-easy via whalebrew

```
$ whalebrew install tsub/graph-easy
```

Now run it via

```
$ echo '[a]->[b]' | graph-easy

+---+     +---+
| a | --> | b |
+---+     +---+
```

Comment: Note for those going cpanminus route without docker :

do note that if you use cpanm (cpanminus) via homebrew, it will invoke dependancy perl which installs to /usr/local/Cellar/perl/<perl version>/bin/graph-easy. thus on each version upgrade of perl, you will lose the link to graph-easy binary. You can either

(1) install packages invoking a local dir (brew info perl) or 
(2) reinstall all packages everytime you upgrade perl

Comment: I haven't heard of whalebrew until this. If you're scared of having to run things inside a docker container, don't be. `Whalebrew creates aliases for Docker images so you can run them as if they were native commands`

Comment: @mirageglobe Thank you for showing me `whalebrew`. What a wonderful use case you've provided!

Comment: `whalebrew install tsub/graph-easy` fails with "failed to inspect docker image: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?" on macOS 14.2.1

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye looks like your docker desktop is not running. try starting docker desktop