# Function to visualize graph (DAG) in terminal

Tags: python, git, command-line-interface

Ask: Python way to visualize a DAG in terminal

I have a graph object with each node with the following structure:

```py
class Node:
    id: int
    category: str
```

Multiple nodes together make a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) that I want to visualize in the terminal. This visualization would be very similar to how we can visualize git commit graph via `git log --all --graph --decorate`:
[Git commit visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa4pT.png)

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/3391213/748102

Comment: Why just Python? See [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452), which has many methods.

Comment: @torek I'm not necessarily visualizing git. I have my own DAG that I want users to be able to visualize in the CLI.

Comment: @BarakItkin this is almost what I'm looking for. Thanks! My only concern is that it's an API that may not be maintained in the future.

Comment: The "pretty Git branch graphs" shows LaTeX, graphviz, and other solutions, all of which work with arbitrary input, not just Git DAGs.